# HTML5 audio control greyed out when playing from external hard drive

Tags: html

Im trying to play mp3 files from an external hard drive connected to raspberry pi on web browser (webserver is the raspberry pi). My code is so far simply to test.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="kyon.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
  <p> <audio controls>
        <source src="shakira.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
  <p> <audio controls>
      <source src="/mnt/SEAGATE_BACKUP_1/MP3/Carly_I_Really_Like_You.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can play first two mp3 but cannot play the third, I have checked permissions which seem fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? What happens when you open the URL directly?

Comment: Just the same, first two I can play the third one is greyed out.

Comment: I have changed the third tag to "file://192.168.1.101/share/MP3/50s.Jukebox/50s.Jukebox/50s_Jukebox/Disc%2002/09%20-%20Tommy%20Edwards%20-%20It's%20All%20In%20The%20Game.mp3"

but still no good, but the url plays on the web browser (chrome) fine.

Comment: when i symlink /mnt/SEAGATE_BACKUP_1/MP3/Carly_I_Really_Like_You.mp3 to a file it works!!!! It looks like for some reason it cannot play files from external hdd and I got no idea why

Comment: Seems like the browsers are having a hard time accessing the mounted hardware. I can't tell what's causing it with the info you provided, you could try digging deeper on the mounting details. Or it could be related to your server, you could also check on that. Or it could be some security policy, etc.

Comment: Thanks rafaelcastrocouto, the files that can play have same permission as that of the one that it cannot play, the symlink has the same permission. I will try to mount and unmount again and will see. I will keep updated.

Comment: I fixed it by mounting hdd in documentroot.

Comment: No, it didnt fix it. Now I dont know how to fix it

Comment: you could try to make a server that copies the files from the seagate hd to the local machine. but if you are not used to create servers it might be harder than finding your true issue

Comment: Thanks, since Im running this all from a raspberry pi my space is limited and also not a very smart thing to do. 
Its seems like I have to play with apache config and .htaccess and also mod_rewrite to redirect to hdd mount.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the python gTTS framework, and get_urls() gave me 2 translate.google.com URLs. My sound controls were also grayed out, and when I copy and pasted the URL into another tab, it gave me a 404 error. I pressed "Reload" and it worked, when I reloaded my own site that used get_urls(), the controls became normal. In short, if you use Chrome, try this:

1. Open it in an actual tab, and reload the page.
2. Reload your own server.
3. Hopefully, it works!

   SHacker (left my login credentials on my Raspberry Pi)